# How useful is a user who only asks questions?

Tags: discussion

If a user asks about 25 questions in a month, which are good enough to earn them 1000 rep, then how useful is that person for the community, if they have never answered any questions?

Comment: How useful? About this much `<-------------->` (note: not to scale)

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem. You can't have answers without questions.

Comment: If a user asks 25 questions that get them 1000 rep, each question is averaging 8 up-votes. That's fairly consistently high quality questions. That's a better contribution than someone like me, with nearly a hundred answers but just over 2000 rep.

Comment: Rep is generally given for things that are considered useful - if they have 1000 rep, they're useful!

Comment: I think I got my answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Questions are the seeds of all content on SO. No questions, no "Q&A". *Good* questions help everyone, specifically people with the same problem which will find these questions in the future with their respective solutions. That's exactly what SO is for.

If a user is able to post such great questions that they accumulate 1000 rep with 25 questions, that user is very valuable for seeding the knowledge base with useful material.

Comment: Not only do they help people with the same problem, they also bring people to the site who enjoy answering questions. I would probably answer more questions if I could find more good ones. And I would most definitely have more fun answering if more of them were of high quality. So the **everyone** in your first paragraph is really key.